# yarn Error fast-abi repository not found

Tags: 0x

I am trying to install 0x-api on windows. On running yarn, I get the error: `error D:\crypto\0x-api\node_modules\fast-abi: Command failed.` `response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/0xProject/fast-abi/releases/download/0.0.2/node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gz`

If you follow the link there really is nothing there. I looked at the node_modules/fast-abi/package.json file that references "package_name": "{node_abi}-{platform}-{arch}.tar.gz".
How can I change this to the available version for Windows?
What files related to this error do I still need to change to install 0x-api?

Answer (score 0):

There is no windows release for fast-abi at the moment, only linux and darwin

Comment: A few weeks ago I already installed 0x-api and did not have this error